# I Can't activate Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to run this code: http://jsfiddle.net/2VL7b/

this is for the php file:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="id1"/><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="id2"/>
```

And Here Is the js file:

```
$('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
$('input[name=radioknof]').on('click', function(){ 
   $(this).next().prop('disabled',false).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

but when I linked javascript to the php file. it won't work.
even when I put javascript in php file directly, it still won't work...

anyone could help me..

Comment: link the javascript at the end of the body ... Other js might be interfering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclosure your code into the ready function to ensure the html document is loaded before your script is executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
    $('input[name=radioknof]').on('click', function(){            
        $(this).next().prop('disabled',false).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
    });
});
```

Otherwise your code could access DOM elements that are not rendered yet.

([Documentation: .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))

Answer (score 2):

```
$document.ready(function(){
   $('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
   $('input[name=radioknof]').on('click', function(){            
      $(this).next().prop('disabled',false).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
   });
});
```